# Ubuntu: make a hotkey to switch to browser window

Tags: ubuntu, hotkeys

I'd like to map <kbd>F3</kbd> to set the focus to my current Firefox window.

How can I do this on Ubuntu?

Answer (score 0):

well I don't have commenting rights, but I just asked and answered a similar question on unix stackexchange - https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/13207/is-it-possible-to-raise-a-window-using-dbus-in-gnome3

I think the same trick should work for gnome2 as well, if thats what you are using.

Comment: What stops you from putting some of its contents here? :) I don't think that's frowned upon.

Comment: umm duplication which is essentially a waste of time?